# SQLite transactions freeze on Dispatchers.Main but work on Dispatchers.Default and Dispatchers.IO

Tags: android, transactions, android-sqlite, kotlin-coroutines

I am working on a project on which I unfortunately cannot use ROOM to access the database because it depends heavily on cursors which read databases created as a result of api calls

So to make this work I am using a normal `SQLiteOpenHelper` to get a `readableDatabase` and perform the queries using something like

```
withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { db.execSQL(.....) }
```

I faced a problem with transactions which created deadlocks, for example this would cause problems

```
suspend fun readDataFromServer() {
    withContext(dispatchers.IO) { db.beginTransaction() } 
    val inputStream = withContext(dispatchers.IO) { client.getDataStream() }

    while(true) {
       withContext(dispatchers.IO) { //code here that reads from the input stream until it finds a separator 
       }
       withContext(dispatchers.Default) { 
           //code that does some calculations that may take anywhere from 500 to 1500 ms
       }

       withContext(dispatchers.IO) { 
           //code that saves the data in the appropriate form in my db
       }

    }
    withContext(dispatchers.IO) { 
         db.setTransactionSuccessful() 
         db.endTransaction()
    }

}
```

(note that the above is some off the top of my head dummy code, I don't have access to my project atm)

I researched it and it seems that the problem was that the transaction has to start and finish at the same thread, so when I used withContext to change the dispatchers (even if that was the same dispatcher) it would cause a deadlock

In the end I solved my problem by wrapping the whole function in one withContext but I noticed something curious

normally the function would start from something like:

```
launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
    readDataFromServer()
}
```

and that would cause a freeze, but when I tried launching it from other dispatchers it would work, so

```
launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
    readDataFromServer()
}
```

and

```
launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    readDataFromServer()
}
```

both seem to work

I was wondering why that is , and if this may be a fluke because in essence I don't use more than one thread for my operations

is wrapping it in the same withContext the correct answer ? or could is using the launch(Dispatchers.Default) correct too?

I am asking because between reading from the server and writing to the database I do some quite intensive work , and it seems incorrect that I have to do that work in the IO dispatcher instead of the Default one

Comment: `why that is` -- `Main` means the main GUI thread and it freezes the app.

Comment: Execution will stay on the same thread as long as it doesn't encounter a suspension point.

Comment: If you have `withContext(IO) { ioOps(); withContext(Default) { cpuOps() } moreIoOps() }` that should all stay on the same thread because `Default` and `IO` share threads. But note the nesting.

Comment: yeah I finally figured it out about an hour ago, it seems that if you nest withContext it combines the dispatchers, so withContext(IO) { withContext(Default } is essentially withContext(IO + Default) , I solved my problem by creating a wrapper around db, with a  custom single thread dispatcher and use that one only for db operations, so they are always on the same thread no matter what the context the request came from

Comment: No, there is no combining of dispatchers. `IO` and `Default` are internally connected and share threads, with the goal of not having to switch threads when you switch between these two dispatchers.

Comment: `they are always on the same thread no matter what the context the request came from` -- i don't think that's actually useful, it limits you to a single db op at a time while not providing any benefits. If the code within a transaction is suspendable, and if transactions are bound to threads, you'll get several coroutines mixed together in the same transaction. And if the code is not suspendable, there is no danger of it switching threads.